# Gin - struct param is validated as null

Tags: go

I have a function here to create post requests and add a new user of type struct into a slice (the data for the API is just running in memory, so therefore no database):

```
type user struct {
    ID        string `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
}

var users = []user{
    {ID: "1", FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Email: "john.doe@email.com"},
}

func createUser(c *gin.Context) {

    var newUser user

    if len(newUser.ID) == 0 {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "user id is null"})
        return
    }

    users = append(users, newUser)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newUser)
}
```

Eveything worked fine, until i tried to make an 'if statement' that checks if an id for a user being sent with a post request is null.

The problem is that the if statement returns true, when it should return false. So if i for example try to make a post request with the following data:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email": "jane.doe@email.com"
}
```

The if statement that checks for an id with the length of 0 will be true, and therefore return a StatusBadRequest. If have also tried this way:

```
if newUser.ID == "" {
}
```

But this also returns true when it shouldn't.

If i remove this check and create the POST request it works just fine, and the new added data will appear when i make a new GET request.

Why do these if statements return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new user object with `var newUser user` statement, you are just creating an empty user object. You still have to bind the JSON string you are sending into that object. for that, what you need to do is: `c.BindJSON(&newUser)`. full code will be like:

```golang
func createUser(c *gin.Context) {

    var newUser user
    err := c.BindJSON(&newUser)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    }

    if len(newUser.ID) == 0 {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "user id is null"})
        return
    }

    users = append(users, newUser)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newUser)
}
```

you can check this link for an example provided by Gin: https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/basic/main.go#L61